# Is heroku console secure?

Tags: security, heroku

When doing and running commands in heroku console, via `heroku run console`. Is this a secure connection?

For example, if I am editing a user's password. Will the information from my computer to the heroku console be secure / encrypted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `heroku console` works over SSH. That's why you have to generate an encryption keypair to use Heroku. Your traffic is encrypted.

Comment: The Heroku console actually works over HTTPS to the RESTful Heroku APIs.  The SSH keys that are associated with a Heroku account are used for the "git push".